# I need help to understand logic and solve code using python

Tags: python

My background: I am a Network Engineer and started learning python to automate tasks. I don't have much experience in coding. I need help to understand and solve the coding issue, I've spent numerous hours to solve this coding problem using python but no luck. I have attached what I have done so far on this problem.

```py
# read file
with open("C:\py\logfile.txt") as file:
    next(file)
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    file.close()

matchEst = []
matchFail = []
matchSyn = []
counterEst = 0
counterFail = 0
counterSyn = 0

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()

    if line.find('Established') != -1:
        matchEst.append(line)
    elif line.find('Failed') != -1:
        matchFail.append(line)
    elif line.find('Syn') != -1:
        matchSyn.append(line)

print(matchEst)
print(matchFail)
print(matchSyn)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established', '9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.2   0:10        Established', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established']
['9/1/2013              1.1.1.2   0:10        Failed', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Failed', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Failed', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Failed']
['9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Syn', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Syn', '9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Syn']
```

Code Description: To parse file "logfile.txt" and print the counts of the status for every IP per day.

```
cat logfile.txt                     
-----------------                   
Date                  IP        Time        State    
9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established
9/1/2013              1.1.1.2   0:10        Failed
9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Syn
9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Failed
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Failed
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established
9/2/2013              1.1.1.2   0:10        Established
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Failed
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Established
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Syn
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10        Syn
```

Output should look like:

```
9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   Established         2
9/1/2013              1.1.1.2   Failed    1
9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   Syn         1
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   Established         4
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   Failed    3
9/2/2013              1.1.1.1   Syn         2
9/2/2013              1.1.1.2   Established         1
```

Thank you!

Comment: "solve this coding problem". *What* coding problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are opening the file in `with` statement, that means it closes automatically. No need to call `close()` explicitly.

For any string manipulation/searching it's good to know Regular expression (in Python `re` module). For counting variables you could use `Counter` from `itertools`. Here's an example:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

with open('logfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data_in = f.read()

columns = re.findall(r'([\d\/]+)\s+([\d\.]+)\s+([\d:]+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+)', data_in)
c = Counter(columns)

for (column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4), count in c.items():
    print(column_1, column_2, column_3, column_4, count)
```

Prints:

```
9/1/2013 1.1.1.1 0:10 Established 2
9/1/2013 1.1.1.2 0:10 Failed 1
9/1/2013 1.1.1.1 0:10 Syn 1
9/2/2013 1.1.1.1 0:10 Established 4
9/2/2013 1.1.1.1 0:10 Failed 3
9/2/2013 1.1.1.2 0:10 Established 1
9/2/2013 1.1.1.1 0:10 Syn 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're storing all of your results in lists, just print the length of each list at the end.

```
print("Established count = " + str(len(matchEst)))
print("Failed count = " + str(len(matchFail)))
print("Syn count = " + str(len(matchSyn)))
```

If you're looking to see the count *per* each distinct IP, then there will be more work to do.

Comment: Thank you, Joshua.
Yes, I would like to understand on how to count status for each IP per day.
Can you please give me overview on how to solve this? I want to try by myself.

Comment: @Jin, If your IP addresses exist in your log in the exact same character locations, loop through your log and append to a list of [list of IP addresses and their fail count, establish count, sys count]. (If they're not in the same location, you'll need to read up on RegEx to id your addresses in that string.) Then, create another loop that says "for each list of [ip address/fail/established/sys count] in my list, go through this log and update the appropriate element in the inner list to match the appropriate count. Loop through that list of lists and print out the information from there.

Comment: @Jin I can try to clarify if that doesn't make sense. I'm giving enough details where you may be able to google this on your own and be able to find the answer yourself, as you said you want to try that.